# What does these lines do?

Tags: git, repository

I was looking at http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto and was following along fine until I got to this:

```
$ mkdir /var/www/www.example.org
$ cat > hooks/post-receive
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.org git checkout -f
$ chmod +x hooks/post-receive
```

I can't find any doc online for `GIT_WORK_TREE` and I have no idea what's happening there.

Also why does he set up on the remote `$ git init --bare` shouldn't that be *not* bare as he want to deploy the actual files there?

Comment: A much easier way to work Git is to work with a GUI :D
Just download msysgit and TurtoiseGit (GUI). Here is a tutorial how you can manage your site: http://stofkn.blogspot.com/2012/02/getting-started-git-and-appharbor-easy.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### GIT_WORK_TREE

It's the same as using [`--work-tree`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git.html) with the `git` command.

> `--work-tree=<path>`
>
> Set the path to the working tree. It can be an absolute path or a path relative to the current working directory.
>   This can also be controlled by setting the GIT_WORK_TREE environment
>   variable and the core.worktree configuration variable (see
>   core.worktree in git-config(1) for a more detailed discussion).

---

#### Bare Repository

You can only push to bare repositories. So he does the following:

1. Create a bare repository where you will push to. Store it somewhere like in `/home/git/repos/www.example.org` (on the server).
2. Clone that repository into another folder like `/var/www/www.example.org` (on the server).
3. Point your Apache/httpd to the non-bare repo location.

   ```
   DocumentRoot /var/www/www.example.org
   DocumentRoot /var/www/www.example.org/public # for Rails apps
   ```
4. Add a post-receive hook (`hooks/post-receive`, chmod +x) to the bare repo, which checks out the bare repository when a push is received (i.e. use `GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/www.example.org`). (Note: If you have to reload/restart your server (Ruby apps for example) add something like `service SERVICE_NAME restart` to the hook script as well.)
5. Push from your development machine to the bare repo. The bare repo will now automatically "forward" that push to the repository residing in `/var/www/www.example.org`. The unison of *githooks* and Magic<sup>TM</sup> has now updated your code, you should see changes if you F5 in your browser.

Comment: I don't understand how and where he's accomplishing step 3. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: I added a few steps to elaborate. Better?

Comment: ahh ok, so If I follow the tuts advice, will pushing delete everything on the server that isn't in my local directory? The server came preloaded with some stuff.